# Execution after 1 clock period and stops (Traffic Controller)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The clk in design starts abruptly and so do the other signals, I am not sure why. I cannot determine if there are any combinational loops in the design and how I could fix them.

I'm unable to figure out the problem in this design/testbench.

You can run the code from here https://edaplayground.com/x/YV8A

[image]

I checked the simulation with modelsim, but I'm facing same error (only 1 clock period executed).

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
`define clk_period 10

module traffic_tb ();

    logic           clk;
    logic           rst;

    logic   [2:0]   light_A;
    logic   [2:0]   light_B;
    
    traffic_top DUT (
        .clk_i      (clk), 
        .rst_i      (rst), 
        .light_A_o  (light_A), 
        .light_B_o  (light_B) 
        );

initial clk = 1;
always #(`clk_period/2) clk = ~clk;

initial begin
    rst = 1;
    #(`clk_period);

    rst = 0;
    #(`clk_period);

    rst = 1;
    #(`clk_period);

    #(`clk_period * 1000);
    $stop;
end

endmodule


module traffic_top (
    input                   clk_i,
    input                   rst_i,

    output  logic   [2:0]   light_A_o,
    output  logic   [2:0]   light_B_o

);

    // Using one-hot codes to represent the states
    parameter   s0 = 6'b000001,
                s1 = 6'b000010,
                s2 = 6'b000100,
                s3 = 6'b001000,
                s4 = 6'b010000,
                s5 = 6'b100000;

    // States
    reg [5:0] current_state, next_state;

    // Counter to count delay in traffic lights
    reg [2:0] count;

    // Sequential logic to update state
    always @ (posedge clk_i or negedge rst_i) begin
        if (!rst_i) begin
            current_state <= s0;
            count <= 0;
        end

        else begin
            current_state <= next_state;
        end
    end

    // Combinational logic to update state
    always @ (current_state) begin
        case(current_state) 
            s0  :   if(count < 5)   begin next_state <= s0; count <= count + 1;  end
                    else            begin next_state <= s1; count <= 0;         end

            s1  :   if(count < 1)   begin next_state <= s1; count <= count + 1;  end
                    else            begin next_state <= s2; count <= 0;         end

            s2  :   if(count < 1)   begin next_state <= s2; count <= count + 1;  end
                    else            begin next_state <= s3; count <= 0;         end

            s3  :   if(count < 5)   begin next_state <= s3; count <= count + 1;  end
                    else            begin next_state <= s4; count <= 0;         end
            
            s4  :   if(count < 1)   begin next_state <= s4; count <= count + 1;  end
                    else            begin next_state <= s5; count <= 0;         end

            s5  :   if(count < 1)   begin next_state <= s5; count <= count + 1;  end
                    else            begin next_state <= s0; count <= 0;         end

            default : next_state <= s0; 
        
        endcase
    end

    always @ (*) begin
        case(current_state)
            s0  :       begin   light_A_o = 3'b001; light_B_o = 3'b100; end
            s1  :       begin   light_A_o = 3'b010; light_B_o = 3'b100; end
            s2  :       begin   light_A_o = 3'b100; light_B_o = 3'b100; end
            s3  :       begin   light_A_o = 3'b100; light_B_o = 3'b001; end
            s4  :       begin   light_A_o = 3'b100; light_B_o = 3'b010; end
            s5  :       begin   light_A_o = 3'b100; light_B_o = 3'b100; end
            default :   begin   light_A_o = 3'b100; light_B_o = 3'b100; end
        endcase

    end

    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your design code is that you are trying to increment the count in the combinational `always` block.  This does not follow good Verilog coding style.  Since the sensitivity list is incomplete, the count does not change, leaving the state machine stuck in one state.

A better approach is to use sequential logic for the count.  I separated the `count` logic out into its own `always` block.  I also removed `count` from the `current_state` sequential `always` block.  You should not make assignments to one signal from multiple `always` blocks as you were doing.

```
// Sequential logic to update state
always @ (posedge clk_i or negedge rst_i) begin
    if (!rst_i) begin
        current_state <= s0;
    end
    else begin
        current_state <= next_state;
    end
end

always @ (posedge clk_i or negedge rst_i) begin
    if (!rst_i) begin
        count <= '0;
    end else begin
        case(current_state) 
            s0  :   if(count < 5) count <= count + 1;
                    else          count <= '0;       
            s1  :   if(count < 1) count <= count + 1;
                    else          count <= '0;       
            s2  :   if(count < 1) count <= count + 1;
                    else          count <= '0;       
            s3  :   if(count < 5) count <= count + 1;
                    else          count <= '0;       
            s4  :   if(count < 1) count <= count + 1;
                    else          count <= '0;       
            s5  :   if(count < 1) count <= count + 1;
                    else          count <= '0;       
        endcase
    end
end

// Combinational logic to update state
always @* begin
    case(current_state) 
        s0  :   if(count < 5) next_state = s0;
                else          next_state = s1;
        s1  :   if(count < 1) next_state = s1;
                else          next_state = s2;
        s2  :   if(count < 1) next_state = s2;
                else          next_state = s3;
        s3  :   if(count < 5) next_state = s3;
                else          next_state = s4;            
        s4  :   if(count < 1) next_state = s4;
                else          next_state = s5;
        s5  :   if(count < 1) next_state = s5;
                else          next_state = s0;
        default :             next_state = s0;         
    endcase
end
```

These changes allow the state machine to transition to other states.

The code now uses blocking assignments for `next_state`, which is another recommended practice.